# how to get iterable collection (queryset) from a more than one ManyToManyField field in Django?

Tags: python, django

I want to get a list of doctors from clinics based on a particular city. I have developed a workaround but it seems expensive operation as I am using a loop to do so.

Clinic Model:

```
class Clinic(models.Model):
   clinic_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   address = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
   doctor = models.ManyToManyField(Doctor, blank=True)
   city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   latitude = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
   longtitude = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
   active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
   created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.clinic_name
```

City Model:

```
    class City(models.Model):
          name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

          def __str__(self):
              return self.name
```

Doctor Model:

```
class Doctor(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, related_name="doctor")
   speciality = models.ManyToManyField(Speciality, blank=True)
   service = models.ManyToManyField(Service, blank=True)
   condition = models.ManyToManyField(Condition, blank=True)

   def __str__(self):
       return f"{self.title} {self.user.full_name}"
```

My workaround is:

```
>>> my_city = City.objects.get(name='Kabul')
>>> clinics = Clinic.objects.filter(city=city)
>>> doctor_list = []
>>> for clinic in clinics:
        doctor_list.extend(clinic.doctor.all())
>>> doctor_list
[<Doctor: Dr. Doctor Khan One>, <Doctor: Prof. Doctor Khan Two>, <Doctor: Dr. Doctor Khan One>, <Doctor: Dr. Doctor Khan One>]
>>> the_result = set(doctor_list)
>>> new_doctor_list = list(the_result)
>>> new_doctor_list
[<Doctor: Dr. Doctor Khan One>, <Doctor: Prof. Doctor Khan Two>]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the iterator:

```
Doctor.objects.filter(clinic__city__name='Kabul').iterator()
```

or all objects:

```
Doctor.objects.filter(clinic__city__name='Kabul').all()
```

Explanation: The filter searches for all doctors that contain a clinic, that contain a city named 'Kabul'